# Haste Haskell->JS compiler does not work on OSX, displaying specific error message when calling hastec

Tags: javascript, macos, haskell, haste

I've tried setting up Haste using the official installation guide. Trying to compile a Hello World produces the following error:

```
Compiling Main into .
Linking haste-compiler/test.js
Linking Main
Linking GHC.Types
Linking GHC.IO.Handle.Text
hastec: /Users/vhsmaia/.haste/jsmods/base/GHC/IO/Handle/Text.jsmod: openBinaryFile: does not exist (No such file or directory)
```

I've then tried to compile the portable version. The error is now:

```
hastec: user error (Haste needs to be rebooted; please run haste-boot
```

Running haste-boot does not amend the error.

Comment: How did you perform the first installation?

Comment: I just followed the steps IIRC, but I had another error. I guess everything is messed up now.

Comment: can you post the file you're trying to compile?

Comment: main = putStrLn "Hello, World!"

Comment: Is the file `/Users/vhsmaia/.haste/jsmods/base/GHC/IO/Handle/Text.jsmod` there?

Comment: No, that's the point, I have no idea why not. jsmods only has ghc-prim inside it.

Comment: I'm a bit late to the party, but is your problem fixed with the latest Haste version (0.2.11)? It sounds like `haste-boot` somehow failed in a highly non-robust way (it used to do that until 0.2.10 or so). If it still fails with 0.2.11, you should get the error while running `haste-boot` instead of afterwards.

I don't have a Mac, so testing Haste on OSX is a bit hard.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem you have, is that `hastec` expects your module to have a Main module. Try renaming your file to `Main.hs` and add a `module Main where` declaration to the top of the file.

Comment: I installed `ghc` and `haskell-platform` using `brew`, and then `hastec` using `cabal` and it worked fine, the file is there. Maybe you can try that.